# How do I scrape a url from xml in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, xml, express, web-scraping

My end goal is to have my app display thumbnails of the X most recent images from a given user's 500px.com account (it's a photography site). The site doesn't have an API, as far as I can tell, but it does have an rss feed for individual users, i.e. https://500px.com/janedoe/rss, that spits out xml.

Using xml2js, I can parse the xml into a js object and navigate to the "description" container that has the html that contains the url I want, like so (this is just a proof of concept using the first item in the rss feed):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var body = new EventEmitter();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {


  request("https://500px.com/janedoe/rss", function(error, response, data) {
        body.data = data;
        body.emit('update');
    }); 

    body.on('update', function() {
        parseString(body.data, function (err, result) {
            var photoLink = result.rss.channel[0].item[0].description[0];
            res.render('index', { title: 'Express', photoName});
        });
    });



});
```

This puts the entire html contents of the "!CDATA" tag in the photoLink variable. What I want to do is target what's in `img src` within that html so I can pass the url as a string to be rendered on the page.

I can envision using string methods to look for the first "img src" tag and then read in until the end of the address, but are there more elegant and easy ways to do this?

Comment: Not a big deal, really. Use an XML parser to parse the RSS and navigate to the elements in question to extract the HTML text. Use an HTML parser to parse the HTML and navigate to the elements in question to extract the attribute values. The one thing you should definitely **not** do is "using string methods".

Comment: Since you have done step #1 already (the RSS parsing), all that's left is step #2 (the HTML parsing). Look at [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) (basically jQuery for node) to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks! Using cheerio worked quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: in this example, i find all the image urls

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const xml = require('fs').readFileSync('feed.xml', 'utf-8')

const template = {
    data: ['//item/description', '.']
}

const result = transform(xml, template)

const links = result.data.map(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    const links = $('img')
    const urls = []
    $(links).each(function(i, link) {
        urls.push($(link).attr('src'))
    })
    return urls
})

console.log(links)
```

Output:

```
[ [ 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/629350/m%3D900/v2?webp=true&sig=4a9fa5788049efb196917cc3f1a55601af901c7157b59ec86c8aa3378c6ee557' ],
  [ 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/625259/m%3D900/v2?webp=true&sig=55eab44535f05625ad25dae3e805b2559c1caeb4c97570d04ee0a77c52c7fb19' ],
  [ 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/625253/m%3D900/v2?webp=true&sig=174d1b27e6f87e0a98192cf6ae051301681a51beb7297df9733956d2763af163' ],
  [ 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/509064/m%3D900/v2?webp=true&sig=698e56114e1d8b67ad11823390f8456ae723d3a389191c43192718f18213caa8' ],
  [ 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/509061/m%3D900/v2?webp=true&sig=2998212f82a1c3428cebb873830a99b908f463474045d4e5ebba3257808685dd' ],
  [ 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/509060/m%3D900/v2?webp=true&sig=8082904fe1935c51fc301a0d10529475ee15124d3797f69cbaeac3fd6c5f0dcb' ],
  [ 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/509056/m%3D900/v2?webp=true&sig=4b85086a7bf55709e77febb202636b0e09415c8ca3fc3657bfb889ad827b3cab' ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks - that approach works well. It looks like camaro performs the same function as xml2js but is faster.

Comment: @testingtesting yes, that's the main purpose of camaro. and ability to transform the xml; not just convert.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a full parser for this just do it with regex :

```
var links = [];
var re    = new RegExp("<img.*?src=['\"](.*?)['\"].*?>", "gmi");
var res;

while(res = re.exec(body)) links.push(res[1]);
```

Example :

```
 var a = '<div class="quote"><div class="quote-profile"><img alt="voyages-sncf.com logo" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="height: 80px" src="/img/app_website/index/logo.jpg"> </div><!--//profile--><img alt="voyages-sncf.com logo" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="height: 80px" src="/img/app_website/index/logo2.jpg" data-attr = "lkjlk"/>'

var links = [];
var re    = new RegExp("<img.*?src=['\"](.*?)['\"].*?>", "gmi");
var res;

while(res = re.exec(a)) links.push(res[1]);
//["/img/app_website/index/logo.jpg", "/img/app_website/index/logo2.jpg"]
```

Comment: Please do not recommend regex for parsing HTML. This has been refuted a million times. It's genuinely bad advice. *"But it avoids a full-blown parser"* is not a justification. HTML parsers are way more complex than regex exactly because regex is not capable of parsing HTML.